# How to know if a closed GitHub issue was fixed or not?

Tags: github, rust

There is [an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/14726) on the [Rust GitHub repository](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust) that someone else opened where I am interested in a solution being provided. The issue is closed, but I don't know if it has been solved or not.

I read the GitHub help pages about issues, but I didn't find what I am looking for.

How can I find out the reason of the closing of that issue? Is this issue fixed? Did they include macros for creating e.g. `HashMap`s with initial values into the standard library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comment chain you can see

> rust-highfive closed this on 25 Dec 2014

You can also see the same user added a comment just before closing the issue

> This issue has been moved to the RFCs repo: [rust-lang/rfcs#542](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/542)

The linked RFC (Request for Comments) is still open implying that it is still open for discussion.

The lifetime for Rust RFCs can be seen at [the-rfc-life-cycle](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs#the-rfc-life-cycle).

It appears the most popular consensus is to current use the [maplit](https://crates.io/crates/maplit) crate.